# MongoDB: Query String with an Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it possible to query/check whether one of the elements in an array is in a comma separated string?

```
Roles = "CRM, PRM"

CurrentRoles = [ "CRM", "Officer" ]
```

So I need to check if one of the arrays in the CurrentRoles Array is in the Roles String?
The variable (CurrentRoles) is what needs to be used in the Query because it is a dynamic field and changes depending on who is logged in.

Query I have so far :

```
{ Roles : { $in: CurrentRoles } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { Roles: { $regex: "CRM" } },
        { Roles: { $regex: "Officer" } }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uDawcsV68UX)

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          { $in: [ "CRM", { "$split": [ "$Roles", ", " ] } ] },
          { $in: [ "Officer", { "$split": [ "$Roles", ", " ] } ] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EbEP1gJ1mWW)

Comment: Is it possible to use the variable CurrentRoles? Again this won't be static. The value will change depending on who logs in

Comment: @SandyBee I don't think it's possible to use the variable CurrentRoles. I know this won't be static. You can achieve my answer by making it in application level.